# k-space tensor integral in statistical mechanics

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, tensors, statistical-mechanics

[image]

*k* is the modulus of the vector **k**. Please help me to integrate the above tensor expression in the infinite domain of the vector **k**. I have tried to let **u** in the direction of *kz* and then transform the current integral into a spherical coordinate with the following relation:

[image]

And I find **Q** is a symmetric tensor, and Q*xy*=0,Q*xz*=0,Q*yz*=0. However,Q*xx*=Q*yy*≠0,Q*zz*≠0,and Q*xx*≠Q*zz*. I guess **Q** has relevance to the tensor **uu**, the assumption that **u** is in the direction of *kz* is just a simple case.How to conduct this integral in the general case is my question.Thank you very much.